# base pairing within a section of RNA sequence using python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm having a problem getting my code to do exactly what I want. I would like to define a function that takes two numbers as the arguments and used the numbers to look at a section of the RNA code which is previously stored as a string.

Then I would like to count all possible base pairs in the section so that 'a' and 'u' pair and 'g' and 'c' pair. However there has to be a gap of 3 characters between the pairs and the pairs cannot crossover. e.g. if rna[4] pairs with rna[10], rna[5] cannot pair with rna[12]. however if a pair occurred between 4 and 10 i.e. 5 and 9 that would be ok.

so far I have

```
def base_pairs(x,y):
return (x=='a' and y=='u' or
    x=='u' and y=='a' or
    x=='c' and y=='g' or
    x=='g' and y=='c' or
    x=='g' and y=='u' or
    x=='u' and y=='g' )

rna = raw_input('Enter RNA sequence: ')
n = len(rna)

def opt(x,y):
    for i in range(x,y-5):
        j = i+4
        if base_pairs(rna[i],rna[j])==1:
            print i,j
            a = i
            b = j
            if b-a > 3:
                if base_pairs(a+1,b-1)==1:
                    print a+1,b-1
                    a = a+1
                    b = b-1
        else:
            j=j+1
```

for example when I input accguugacgcag I would like to use opt(0,12) and get 0,4 5,11 6,10
currently I only get 0,4

Comment: You might want to give some examples. What goes wrong with your current code? Give us a few bits of example input, what you currently get, and what you want to get.

Comment: I don't understand your description of what you want, but here are a few style suggestions.  First, `base_pairs` might be clearer as `are_base_pair`.  Second, you shouldn't compare with 1 for a Boolean function.  Your `if` statements should be just `if base_pairs(a+1,b-1):`  With the changing of the function name that will make that line much clearer: `if is_base_pair(a+1,b-1):`.  Finally, if you named `x`, `y`, `i`, `j`, `a`, and `b` more descriptively the error might pop out at you.

Comment: You say "the pairs cannot crossover. e.g. if rna[4] pairs with rna[10], rna[5] cannot pair with rna[12]" but you don't specify how you would pick between the two pairs.  Also, What is the initial `x` and `y` in `opt`? If you can explain these things, I think I could suggest fixes for your function.

Comment: thank you for your comments.The initial x and y are the indexes for the chosen segment which sometimes isn't the full length of the RNA sequence. The next stage was to look at how the pairs where chosen but the best method is to rank the g-c pairs higher than a-u pairs

Comment: If you entered `opt(0,9)`, how do you expect 5,11 and 6,10?  Is that because the 0 to 9 is for the left side of the pairs?

Comment: sorry that should be opt(0,12)

Comment: When I run your code with `rna = 'accguugacgcag'`, `opt(0,12)` produces the following lines of output: `0 4`, `2 6`, `5 9`, and `6 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started on a new version of your function.  I've incorporated the ideas I mentioned in the comments on your question.  In addition, I've made the rna string a parameter, but this could be removed fairly easily.  This version doesn't produce the output you asked for, but it might be adaptable to meet your needs.  The output on my machine is o,4 and 5,9.  I couldn't figure out why you would prefer 5,11 over 5,9 so I couldn't change it to give that result.

```
def is_base_pair(x, y):
    return (x=='a' and y=='u' or
            x=='u' and y=='a' or
            x=='c' and y=='g' or
            x=='g' and y=='c' or
            x=='g' and y=='u' or
            x=='u' and y=='g' )

# start and end are the inclusive range of places in which to look for pairs
def opt(rna, start, end):
    # if the range is too small, give up
    if start + 4 > end:
        return

    # the next left side to try to match
    nextLeft = start

    while nextLeft + 4 <= end:
        # find the right nucleobase to match the one at nextLeft
        #   start looking at the minimal distance and incrementally get bigger
        potentialRight = nextLeft + 4
        while not is_base_pair (rna[nextLeft], rna[potentialRight]) and potentialRight <= end:
            potentialRight += 1

        if is_base_pair (rna[nextLeft], rna[potentialRight]):
            print nextLeft, potentialRight
            # recursively search for pairs between the elements of this pair
            opt(rna, nextLeft + 1, potentialRight - 1)
            nextLeft = potentialRight + 1
        else:
            nextLeft += 1
```

Let me know if you have any questions on how this works.

Comment: This is brilliant Thank You! The reason for choosing 5,11 over 5,9 is that 5,11 is more preferable, the problem relates to RNA folding and this pair is more stable. I think thats why I was having issues because I wasn't clearly defining the restrictions I wanted on the code.